# Choosing sans-serif font, without changing anything else

Tags: math-mode, sans-serif, roman

How do I make Arev the font for the sans-serif family, but nothing else? I tried using

```
\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

as instructed on [this](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/arev/) page, but that made everything sans-serif. I want the body of my text and everything from math mode and stuff to be roman, specifically Antiqua. Anywhere where I havent specified

```
\sffamily
```

I want to be in something different from Arev.

I have tried coming up with a solution using different ways, but none got me all the way where I wanted, and most were quite messy. Anyone know of a quick fix? Doesn't sound like it should be that hard.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fav}` instead of `\usepackage{arev}`, which is quite a “greedy” package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `arev` is “greedy”: it changes everything to (the Arev clone of) the Vera Sans font.

The `arevtext.sty` package essentially does

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{fav}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fav}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{fvm}
```

and you just need the second line. So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fav}
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I also wanted to try the Gillius package, but this one also seems to be fairly greedy. However, I can't make out anything by reading its .sty files. Any ideas?

Comment: @Deltat `gillius` should act only on the sans serif family, if not called with the `default` option. So `\usepackage{gillius}` should work.